# convert a data frame into a specifically formatted frequency table

Tags: r

I have a data.frame and I'm trying to create a frequency table that shows the frequency of values for each row. So I'm starting with something like this:

```
d <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(3,4,5), c=c(1,2,5))
```

which looks like this:

```
  a b c
  1 3 1
  2 4 2
  3 5 5
```

What I'd really like to create is a contingency data.frame or matrix that looks like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

The top row is simply a label row and need not be in the final result. But I add it there for illustration. Each row shows the digits 1:9 and the number of times each digit shows up in each row of the starting data.

I can't wrap my head around an easy way to create this. Although it seems like the `table()` function should be helpful, I can't get it to give me any love. Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: You have a data.frame full of numbers?  How quickly you forget, grasshopper... use a matrix.

Comment: Does using a matrix change the answer?

Comment: It doesn't change Josh O'Brien's answer because `apply` automatically converts it first argument to a matrix/array.  I'm not sure about Ilya's.  I was mostly teasing anyway. ;-)

Comment: i know you were kidding, but it did make me wonder...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go:

```
t(apply(d, 1, tabulate, nbin=9))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    2    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    2    0    0    0    0
```

(Though it probably doesn't matter in this application, `tabulate()` (which is used inside of the code for `table()`) is also nice for the impressive speed with which it performs its calculations.)

---

**EDIT**: `tabulate()` isn't set up to deal with 0s or negative integers. If you want another one liner that does, you could use `table()` though, doing something like this:

```
d <- data.frame(a=c(0,-1,-2), b=c(3,4,5), c=c(1,2,5))

t(apply(d, 1, function(X) table(c(X, -9:9)) - 1))
     -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
[1,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
[2,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
[3,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Definitely (another) one of those simple gems of base R. Thanks again R-core!

Comment: any way to make it accomodate zero and negative values? Upon inspecting my use case, those are more important than I realized when I did the simple question.

Comment: @JDLong -- I added a one-liner using `table()` that deals gracefully with zero and negative integers. You'd just need to adjust the `-9:9` bit to cover whatever range you're interested in, and any numbers outside of that range will still be included in the table.  By adding a few preliminary lines that check for the range of the integers in the original data.frame and set the range in the output table, you could easily wrap this up into a nice little function to do what you want. Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

another solution using table

```
library(reshape)
d <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(3,4,5), c=c(1,2,5))
d2 <- melt(d)
d2$rows <- rep(1:nrow(d), ncol(d))
table(d2$rows, d2$value)
```

Comment: this has the distinct advantage of handling zeros and negative values properly which was about to be my follow on question. Very nice!